# Create vector based on value another vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have got vector vec and desired result:

```
vec <-    c(1,1,1,20,1,1,1,1,40,1,120,1,1)
result <- c(1,1,1,1 ,2,2,2,2, 2,3,3  ,4,4)
```

Result is created that way: start from one, if value in vec >10, start giving two, if next value >10 start with three and so on.

I tried with:

```
b <- 1
 for (i in 1:length(vec)){
  if(vec[i] < 10){
  vec[i] <- 1
  } else {
   b <- b+1
   vec[i] <- b}}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lag with `cumsum`

```
s=dplyr::lag(vec>10)
s[is.na(s)]=FALSE
cumsum(s)+1
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Comment: Great, but it needs imporvement: it gives:  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4

Comment: @Adamek would you like check it again on my side it shows 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4

Comment: it gives result from my previous comment

Comment: I know, I have to use dplyr's lag. Simple dplyr::lag :)

Comment: @Adamek yep sorry forgot list the package